# Solving $h=\frac{a}{d}$ and $h'=\frac{b}{d}$, where $h,a,b,d \in k[t]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero
and let $h,a,b,d \in k[t]$.

Assume that
$h=\frac{a}{d}$
and
$h'=\frac{b}{d}$,
where $'$ is the derivative w.r.t. $t$.

> What are the solutions for this system ot two equations? Here $h,a,b,d$ are all not known, and we wish to find four polynomials satisfying that system.

My solution is as follows, and I wish to know if it is true or am I missing something?

First observe that $d=1$, $a=h$, $b=h'$ is a solution,
so for arbitrary $h$, we can take $d=1$, $a=h$, $b=h'$
and obtain the above system.

We can differentiate $h=\frac{a}{d}$ and obtain
$h'=\frac{a'd-ad'}{d^2}$,
and so
$\frac{a'd-ad'}{d^2}=\frac{b}{d}$,
hence
$a'd-ad'=bd$.

Divide both sides by $ad$ (if it's not zero) and obtain that
$\frac{a'}{a}-\frac{d'}{d}=\frac{b}{a}$.

Integrate boyh sides and get
$\ln(a)-\ln(d)=\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha$,
for some $\alpha \in k$.

Then,
$\ln(\frac{a}{d})=\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha$, and then
$e^{\ln(\frac{a}{d})}=e^{\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha}$,
yielding,
$\frac{a}{d}=e^{\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha}$.

But $h=\frac{a}{d}$, so we have
$k[t] \ni h=e^{\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha}$.

Therefore, $\int{\frac{b}{a}}+\alpha = \ln(h)$.

It is clear that $\alpha=0$ and $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{h'}{h}$ is a solution
(with arbitrary $d$), but this follows immediately from the system and I wish to find a more specific solution, if possible.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If you don't impose $\gcd(a,d)=1$ then every $h\in Frac(k[t])$ has such an expression. If you do impose $\gcd(a,d)=1$ then $h$ has no pole, $d=1$.

Comment: @reuns, thank you for your comment, interesting. Please, if you can slightly elaborate it into an answer, it would be nice. Here $h \in k[t]$.

Comment: Not sure what you think is mysterious. Given $h,d$ take $a = hd, b = h'd$

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have seen this immediate solution, but I wonder if there is a more accurate form. Maybe a more accurate form can be obtained only is we further assume that $\gcd(a,d)=1$, so $1=\gcd(a,d)=\gcd(hd,d)=d$.